# Where is AuthenticatesUsers on laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

I build basic Auth in laravel 5.3 user make:auth. In laravel 5.3 they separate login and register controller in `Auth\LoginController` and `Auth\RegisterController`.

Below is my `Auth\LoginController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

     /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm try to edit `AuthenticatesUsers` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`, that not affected at all. I even try to rename the class/trait name on `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`, but the script still works.

So where is the actual `AuthenticatesUsers`? Because my sublime can only find one file with that name.

Thank You

Comment: It's not recommended to edit files in Vendor Directory, if you want you can extend the class and redefine the function.

Answer (score 9):

There is only one `AuthenticatesUsers`, and it will be in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`. If you're editing it and it's not having any effect then you could be editing the file in a different project.

It's worth noting that you *should never* edit this file anyway. Everything in your `vendor/` folder should be left as-is, as when Composer runs it will replace any changes you've made. If you want to make changes you should extend or override the methods you need to.

Comment: This trait no longer exists in Laravel 10.

Comment: Correct - I believe this is now part of Laravel UI instead of the core framework.